# Веing a tutor in Germany

Tags: germany, working

Imagine one has no work permit and enters Germany with a tourist visa or a job seeker visa or a student visa.
Is it legal to be a tutor? 
What are the legal consequences of tutoring? 
e.g. may one be deported or have troubles with next visa?
I think that it is a minor crime so it is not de facto punishable. 
Will one obtain some fines(how much?) or be charged with something?

Comment: According to https://www.zoll.de/EN/Businesses/Work/Foreign-domiciled-employers-posting/Residence-title/Consequences-of-non-compliance/consequences-of-non-compliance_node.html the penalty for illegal working is a fine of up to €5000, and for repeated offences a fine and imprisonment may result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to your question depend on your citizenship, whether you have a visa, and what type of visa. Illegal working is not considered a ‘minor crime’ in any jurisdiction. Assuming you are not an EU citizen, in simple terms:

Tourist visa/visa-free national: working is not permitted. The consequences of non-compliance can be severe for all concerned - a fine of up to €5000 and possibly imprisonment. Deportation proceedings for the foreign national illegal worker. https://www.zoll.de/EN/Businesses/Work/Foreign-domiciled-employers-posting/Residence-title/Consequences-of-non-compliance/consequences-of-non-compliance_node.html

Job seeker visa: as the name implies, this allows you to enter Germany to search for work during a stay of up to 6 months. It does not mean you can start working immediately without the relevant work visa/permit https://www.germany-visa.org/job-seeker-visa/

Student visa: working alongside your studies is permitted within certain limits https://www.topuniversities.com/student-info/careers-advice/how-work-germany-during-or-after-your-studies